# Pandas column name of the max cell value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max, cumsum

I have a df which has some codes in the leftmost column and a forward profile in the other columns (df1 below)

df1:

```
   code        tp1        tp2        tp3        tp4        tp5       tp6  \
0  1111   0.000000   0.000000   0.018714   0.127218   0.070055  0.084065   
1   222   0.000000   0.000000   0.000418   0.000000   0.017540  0.003015   
2   333   1.146815   1.305678   0.384918   0.688284   0.000000  0.000000   
3   444   0.000000   0.000000   1.838797   0.000000   0.000000  0.000000   
4   555  27.190002  27.134837  24.137560  17.739465  11.990806  8.631395   
5   666   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  0.000000   

        tp7        tp8        tp9       tp10  
0  0.019707   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  
1  6.594860  10.535905  15.697232  21.035824  
2  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  
3  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  
4  7.476197   6.461532   5.570051   4.730345  
5  0.000000   0.000068   0.000000   0.000000
```

I want the output to be a 3 column df (df2 below) which has the column name of the cell (for each code) which has the last number (+ve or -ve) after which there are only 0s. The 2nd Column (`tp_with_max_num`) will have the column name which has the max such number.

df2:

```
   code max_tp tp_with_max_num
0  1111    tp7             tp4
1   222   tp10            tp10
2   333    tp4             tp2
3   444    tp3             tp3
4   555   tp10             tp1
5   666    tp8             tp8
```

Using this : [name of column, that contains the max value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34200153/name-of-column-that-contains-the-max-value)
i was able to get the 3rd column:

```
input_df['tp_with_max_num'] = input_df.ix[0:6,1:].apply(lambda x: input_df.columns[1:][x == x.max()][0], axis=1)
```

I am unable to solve for the 2nd column in df2....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Knowing that [idxmax](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) returns the index of the *first* maximum, you can use cumsum to find the column after which there are only zeros:

```
df.ix[:, 'tp1':].cumsum(axis=1).idxmax(axis=1)
Out[61]: 
0     tp7
1    tp10
2     tp4
3     tp3
4    tp10
5     tp8
dtype: object
```

Comment: You'll have to slightly change it to also work with negative numbers, though. There are none in the questions example but there might be some later on, so you could ad a call to `abs` before doing the `cumsum`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `argmax` on the row to return the column name with the largest value for the 2nd column if you temporarily replace `0` with `NaN` then you can use `last_valid_index` to return the column with the last non-zero value:

```
In [117]:
df['max_tp'], df['tp_with_max_num'] = df.ix[:,'tp1':].replace(0,np.NaN).apply(lambda x: x.last_valid_index(), axis=1), df.ix[:,'tp1':].apply(lambda x: x.argmax(), axis=1)
df[['max_tp','tp_with_max_num']]

Out[117]:
  max_tp tp_with_max_num
0    tp7             tp4
1   tp10            tp10
2    tp4             tp2
3    tp3             tp3
4   tp10             tp1
5    tp8             tp8
```

Comment: nice.. thanks.. any thoughts on the 2nd column? or i will only have to iterate and remove the trailing 0s ?

Answer (score 1):

Faster is use:

```
print (df.ix[:,'tp1':].idxmax(axis=1))
0     tp4
1    tp10
2     tp2
3     tp3
4     tp1
5     tp8
dtype: object
```

**Timings**:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [128]: %timeit (df.ix[:,'tp1':].idxmax(axis=1))
100 loops, best of 3: 5.9 ms per loop

In [129]: %timeit (df.ix[:,'tp1':].apply(lambda x: x.argmax(), axis=1))
1 loop, best of 3: 237 ms per loop

In [130]: %timeit (df.ix[:,'tp1':].replace(0,np.NaN).apply(lambda x: x.last_valid_index(), axis=1))
10 loops, best of 3: 126 ms per loop

In [131]: %timeit (df.ix[:, 'tp1':].cumsum(axis=1).idxmax(axis=1))
100 loops, best of 3: 6.71 ms per loop
```

So the faster is my and [ayhan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38762508/2901002) solution.

Comment: understood.. just earned the right to do so :) did that.. thanks!

Comment: You can do it, because your reputation is higher as 15 ;)